# How to prevent truncation using pd.read_sas()

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I am new to python and use the follwing code to read in a sas-file:

```
df=pd.read_sas('C:\\test\\test.sas7bdat', format = 'sas7bdat', encoding = 'latin-1')
```

There are columns which have either a 7-string code or just "M" for missing. Columns where the first rows just have a M in the first couple of rows and only in later rows the 7-string codes are truncated to just one character for all rows, which does not happen for rows where I have a 7-string code in the first rows.

[this is how the original data looks like in sas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfUR8.png)

How can I prevent pandas to truncate the text when reading in the data?

Thank you.
Lia

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the data should look like?  If you don't have SAS you can use a free version of SAS Viewer to do so.

Comment: Are the columns numeric with special missing value .M for missing?

Comment: The columns are character variables with either a 7-character/number string or M if there is missing information.

Comment: I integrated a snapshot of how the data look like in sas above, it reads the first two correct but neither the third or fourth.

Comment: You could try different python package... https://pypi.org/project/sas7bdat/ has worked with me.